# React Routes component giving this is undefined on axios interceptor

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, axios

I am creating an axios interceptor to catch application wide 500 errors and to display an error page.
I am new to React, this is on existing codebase by someone else.

The issue I am facing is that axios interceptor actually does working, but when I try to set the state to render a component it fails

```
this.setState({ userLoaded: true, serverError: true });
```

giving:

> Exception has occurred. Error: **this** is undefined

In Routes.js we have this:

```
const Routes = observer(class Routes extends React.Component {
  state = { userLoaded: false, serverError: false, serverUnauthorized: false };

  componentDidMount() {
    getMe().then(data => {
      userStore.setCurrentUser(data);
      companyStore.loadSettings();
      this.setState({ userLoaded: true });
    }).catch(({ response }) => {
      if (response.status === 401)
        this.setState({ userLoaded: true, serverUnauthorized: true });
      else if (response.status === 400)
        this.setState({ userLoaded: true, serverError: true });
      else
        this.setState({ userLoaded: true, serverError: true });
    });
    // section to catch application wide errors, happening later on the navigation
    Axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
      // Do something with response data
      return response;
    }, function (err) {
      if (err.response.status >= 500) {
        this.setState({ userLoaded: true, serverError: true }); // <!-- THIS IS FAILING
        console.log('setstate run');
      }
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
  }

render() {
    return (
         this.state.userLoaded ?
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ScrollToTop>
        <Switch>
          {
            this.state.serverUnauthorized ?
              <Route component={Page401} />
              :
              this.state.serverError ?
                <Route component={Page500} />
... simplified ...       
    );
  }
});
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there a better way to get this intercepted and error screen displayed?

Comment: I think the problem is [binding of `this` in JS](https://javascript.info/bind). When you pass the error handler to the axios interceptor as `function`, `this` will not be bound to the current class' context. Try using a fat arrow function (`err =>`) when passing the handler to the response interceptor.

Comment: Define the axios interceptors as arrow functions. Check the duplicate 

```Axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
      // Do something with response data
      return response;
    }, (err) => {
      if (err.response.status >= 500) {
        this.setState({ userLoaded: true, serverError: true }); // <!-- THIS IS FAILING
        console.log('setstate run');
      }
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });```